# Convert IntelliJ IDEA project to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, intellij-idea, junit

I am trying to export IntelliJ IDEA 14 project to Eclipse (a console hello world template with JUnit) using "Export to Eclipse" in menu, but when I import it in Eclipse (4.4.1) via Import—>Existing Projects Into Workspace it says

```
Unbound classpath variable: 'APPLICATION_HOME_DIR/lib/junit-4.11.jar
```

Without JUnit it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import fails because your project references the JUnit jar from the IntelliJ IDEA distribution. You need to put the jar under your own project directory.